# Java 17 on Raspberry Pi for Minecraft 1.18

Tags: java

I'm having issues finding a way to install Java 17 on my RPi. It seems like anything I do, it either reverts to JDK11 or 16. This would be running the latest Raspbian.

Does anyone have any tips that I could follow to get Java 17 to be the active version?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to clarify where you got the tarball from (I think currently oracle is the only source).   You'll also need to be using a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sudo update-alternatives --config java`?

This adds symbolic links to your /usr/bin folder. This way your system shouldn't revert back to java11/16 - unless for example the program you're running has their own path to a java installation.

Another option would be to change your PATH in ~.profile or ~.bashrc.
You can add your java17 installation path to the PATH like this, but I think you'd have to delete the java11/16 from the path for this to work:

`PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/java17/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I download the "Full" JDK from BellSoft as it is complied with DIO support for Raspberry Pi and also includes OpenJFX.  There are 64 or 32-bit versions:

https://bell-sw.com/

Get the regular Java SE JDK, not the embedded version.

The .deb installed cleanly on my RPi 3 B.